# Using negative numbers in pandas.DataFrame.query() expression

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use the pandas.DataFrame.query() function as follows:

```
expression_string = 'ColumnName<(-1000)'
output_dataframe = dataframe.query(expression_string)
```

The code works with positive numbers, but when negative numbers are passed to the string, as above, it returns the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'UnaryOp' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Any suggestions on how to use negative numbers in DataFrame query() expressions? Thank you!!

Comment: What version of Pandas are you using?

Comment: 0.22.0, I think it's the latest  version

Comment: My python version is 3.6.3

Comment: Any `None` or `NaN` in the column?

Comment: @miradulo I don't think that's the problem, if it was the code would not work with positive numbers either

Comment: @chrisz No, all values are numbers of float64 datatype

Comment: Related? https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11235

Comment: Yes, it's the exact same issue but was not resolved on that thread/ any linked threads

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce this error on `pandas` v0.20.3 with specific data types; for example, `np.float32`. The workaround is to cast explicitly as `float`.

This is a known bug: [DataFrame.eval errors with AttributeError: 'UnaryOp'](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16363)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [-3.0, -2.5, -1.5, 3.0]}, dtype=np.float32)

x = 'A>(-1)'

# AttributeError:
res = df.query(x)

# Success:
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(float)
res = df.query(x)
```