# AttributeError: 'UnaryOp' object has no attribute 'evaluate' when using eval function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, eval, conditional-operator

```
for test_ind, case_data in test_df.iterrows():
      case_data = case_data.to_frame().T
      rule = "Ask_before>-0.4843681 & 0.5255821<=BidVol_before<=0.07581073 & Volume>0.1107559"
      print(case_data, "case_data")
      if case_data.eval(rule).all() == True:
          print("TRUE")
```

Here, when the rule contains negative values, this error will appear. Could you please help me to fix this. I need to check whether this rule applies to the instances in the data-frame. Ask_before, BidVol_before are the columns of the dataframe test_df. Could you please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Could you share test_df or a sample of it?

Comment: test_sf is a data frame with columns such as Ask_before, BidVol_before and Volume. Assume values of those columns can be any floating number.

Comment: `data = [[-0.5, -3.5, 3.8],[-0.7, -0.5, -0.38]] 
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Ask_before', 'BidVol_before',Volume])`

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with `pandas '1.0.5'`. It is working for me with the data you provided. Check your pandas version just in case.

Comment: recently, face the same problem. try to cast to float as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400843/using-negative-numbers-in-pandas-dataframe-query-expression
it solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a problem in your code, it's a bug in pandas https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16363
It is fixed by now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's still open as of 2022 January
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16363
in my experience resolving negative index values solved iit

Answer (score 0):

Change the "unary" to an simple expression works for me, e.g. -5 -> (0 - 5)